# Solution of a DAE system of two ODE of second degree

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, constraints

I should solve the following DAE system:
$$\ddot{x}(t)=-\alpha y(t)$$
$$\ddot{y}(t)=\beta x(t)$$
with the conditions:
$x(t)\ge0$, $y(t)\ge0$
and $x(t)+y(t)=N$ 
with $N\gt 0$.
I'm able to solve the system, but I don't know how put the constrains. Thanks.